# Modifying adjacency matrix based on edges

Tags: python, networkx

I have the adjacency matrix, `H` of a graph. I delete the first and last rows and columns to generate a new matrix, `H1`. In `H1`, I would like to replace the diagonal with number of edges each vertex has with a negative sign. The graph, the current and desired outputs follow

[image]

```
import numpy as np
H = np.array([
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
])

H1 = H[1:-1, 1:-1]
print([H1])
```

Current output:

```
array([[0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0]])]
```

Desired output:

```
array([[-2, 1, 1],
       [1, -2, 1],
       [1, 1, -2]])]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.identity`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.identity.html) and [`numpy.ndarray.sum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.sum.html) to achieve that. I.e.

```
>>> H1 - np.identity(3)*H1.sum(axis=1)
array([[-2.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1., -2.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1., -2.]])
```